# Implicit ParameterBinderFactory[org.joda.time.LocalDateTime] for the parameter type

Tags: scala, implicit

I brought up the scalikejdbc version and got an error like this:

> [error]  Implicit ParameterBinderFactory[org.joda.time.LocalDateTime]
> for the parameter type org.joda.time.LocalDateTime is missing. [error]
> You need to define ParameterBinderFactory for the type or use
> AsIsParameterBinder.

```
  def toUpdaters: Seq[(SQLSyntax, ParameterBinder)] = {
    val ses = SeasonProjection.column
    Seq(
      start.map(ses.start -> _) //<- here
```

How can I solve the problem?

I have not found any examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out the documentation at http://scalikejdbc.org/documentation/operations.html, section *Using joda-time library*.

You need to add a library to allow scalikejdbc to work with Joda:

```scala
libraryDependencies += "org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc-joda-time" % "3.5.0"
```

Then use appropriate imports in your code like:

```scala
// If you need ParameterBinderFactory for joda-time classes
import scalikejdbc.jodatime.JodaParameterBinderFactory._
// If you need TypeBinder for joda-time classes
import scalikejdbc.jodatime.JodaTypeBinder._
```

---

That being said, you might want to get rid of Joda in favour of `java.time` which is nowadays standard for date/time representations and is most of the time supported out-of-the-box by libraries.